# Tumblr: photoUrl-(size) - size depending on class?

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr

I have a [Tumblr Site](http://cubetestalmond.tumblr.com) where the width of each post is determined by a tag.

If a post is tagged with `#width200`, the css class `.width200` is assigned.

The problem is, though the posts have different widths, they all load the same size photo using the theme operator: `{{PhotoURL-500}}`.

This works, but for the smaller photos, it's a waste of bandwidth. I could use the theme operator `{{PhotoUrl-250}}` but this makes larger photos look bad.

Is there any way around this using theme operators or javascript?

Comment: If you're not limited on using client side templating, I suggest you use http://handlebarsjs.com/ it has helpers so you can put your javascript logic using it. Note: it also uses mustache so you don't really have a problem applying it on yours.

Comment: Thank you Victor, I'll look into it, but I'm not sure how I'd implement it...

Just wanted to add that I've found at least one blog which somehow accomplishes what I want to do, but I don't know how: http://gastown-theme.tumblr.com

Comment: Interesting question! Sadly you will need to use javascript and data attributes to pass in some replacement URLs and test to see what fits. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates the images on the fly, depending on the hashtag (use `#s0`, `#s1`, `#s2` instead of `#width200`, it's easier)

This defaults to a 400px-wide image when Javascript is not available (and for bots like Google and Facebook)

```
{block:Posts}
    {block:Photo}
        <script id="{PostID}-image" data-images="{PhotoURL-250},{PhotoURL-400},{PhotoURL-500},{PhotoURL-HighRes}" data-classes="{TagsAsClasses}">
            (function () {
                //select current script tag
                var el = document.getElementById("{PostID}-image");

                //get data, this works in IE too
                var sizes = el.getAttribute('data-images').split(',');
                var classes = el.getAttribute('data-classes');

                //figure out which one is selected.
                //use hashtags like "#s1",
                //where 1 is the index of the url in data-images:
                //0 = 250, 1 = 400, 2 = 500, 3 = highres
                var imageIndex = classes.match(/\bs(\d)\b/);
                if (!imageIndex) {
                    imageIndex=[0,"0"];//no hashtag found, default to smallest image size
                }

                //create image and append it after the script tag
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = sizes[imageIndex[1]];
                el.parentNode.insertBefore(img, el.nextSibling);
            } ());
        </script>
        <noscript><img src="{PhotoURL-400}" alt=""></noscript>
    {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}
```

I haven't tested this, but you get the idea. If you find bugs, please edit/fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I had missed the existance of '''{PostID}''', so I wasn't sure how to insert the code.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the fixes. They were rejected by the community (…) so I had to re-apply them manually. I'm glad it works for you :)

Comment: Hmm, while this certainly works, the images won't load at all for those posts that are appended with [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)... any ideas?

Comment: OK, I get it, I need to add a callback to the infinite-scroll code (somehow). But why is the noscript fallback not working? It comes out within brackets, like this: `"<img src="(actual working url)">"`

Comment: It looks like jQuery.load (what infinite-scroll relies on) [executes them **before** they are appended](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution), so `document.getElementById("{PostID}-image")` won't find it. You'd have to pack this script into a separate function and call it when infinitescroll is done loading. `<noscript>` is still not shown because javascript is still technically enabled in the browser.